# Black and decker drill won’t stop spinning

Tags: electrical, repair, drill

As soon as I plug my drill into the mains it starts spinning slowly but won’t stop completely which isn’t ideal when trying to use it, how can fix it?? Could it just be some dust has got into the trigger or something?

Comment: could be dust in the trigger, or the trigger could have some sort of electrical damage.

Comment: A picture or model number would help, as we're all guessing below ;)

Answer (score 2):

My old B&d drill had a small knob on the front of the trigger. When it as screwed in (turned clockwise) it would pull the trigger in. If yours has this function try rotating the knob counter clockwise. As other have stated it is possible that debris is in the switch. Try to manually pull the switch out and see if it stopped spinning.

Comment: Was it speed control as well? I've had that before and got something similar on a Bosch, though on that the lock is separate.  Certainly worth a fiddle

Comment: It would be helpful to note that the small knob is a speed control/trigger lock.

Answer (score 1):

Quick test to see if it's just got a bit dusty/clogged.

Unplug, press & fully release the trigger rapidly a dozen or so times.
If that doesn't make *any* difference whatsoever, then replace the switch mechanism - $£€ 25-30 - better safe than sorry.

If it does make a difference, even if not completely cure it, then invest in a can of contact cleaner - $£€ 5-10 - Don't spray with power connected, allow *plenty* of time to evaporate before re-connecting. You may need to disassemble to reach the switch properly.

(I'm assuming this is a variable resistance, slow-start of some sort. If it's not, just replace the switch.)

Comment: +1 I suspect the trigger lock, which many drills have and is always (IME) mechanical, is damaged, full crud, or inadvertently engaged.  Squeezing the trigger should release it.  An air duster can into the housing near the switch might be worth a shot (or several) before dismantling or using contact cleaner.

Comment: Of course, B&D isn't known for being the highest quality or highest priced brand on the market. The cost of repair parts may well quickly exceed the cost of replacement. That's not to say that there is anything wrong with a B&D product - they're suitable for purpose, they may just not last as long as a more expensive brand.

Comment: My "inadvertently engaged" is because the lock isn't always obvious, or may be of no interest to the OP - my jigsaw has one that I never use, but if I use the saw left-handed the inside of the knuckle at the base of my index finger engages it, and being mechanical, it stays engaged when turned off at the wall.  This is also a good reason to ensure the tool is held/positioned safely before applying power

Comment: @FreeMan another brand that used to be good and solid (decades ago) but can't be assumed to be any more.  Spares may or may not be available for that model

Comment: Presumably if it had some obvious mechanical lock/speed setting the OP would have tried that first… I'm assuming single squeeze trigger, no lock, no dial.